# How can I prevent Telegram from starting automatically on Debian 8.7 Jessie?

Tags: debian, kde, kde4, autostart

I'm using Telegram Desktop on Debian 8.7. It starts automatically even though I've not created any .desktop file under `~/.kde/Autostart`. It's quite annoying as I don't want its window to show up maximised but I'd rather start it with the --startintray flag.
I've also tried to create the .desktop file under the Autostart folder but that seems to not override this weird behaviour.
By opening the running services I can see why this occurs (why telegram opens by itself), I get the following hint when I go over "Telegram" with the cursor:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it! KDE was saving the session upon shutdown and restoring it upon startup, thus reopening all programs.

I disabled it under Startup and `Workspace > Startup and Shutdown > Desktop Session > On Login > Start with an empty session`. (`Restore previous session` was the default)

Comment: It worked for me, although in KDE 5.15 I found that option under `Workspace` then `Statup and Shutdown`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove it from `~/.config/autostart/`.  Or, if it is present in `/etc/xdg/autostart`, then copy it to `~/.config/autostart/` and edit it as desired.